# If you're [blinking], you might miss it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blinking) tag seems to me to be completely useless.

The excerpt is *"Alternate between being visible and invisible."* The wiki is the same text, along with a link to a Wikipedia article on the [blink element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_element). I had hoped that element had died long enough ago that it had turned to dust...

The fact that something is blinking does not seem to be sufficiently relevant to warrant a tag.

There are only 140 questions in this tag, so I could clean it up myself, but wanted to make sure I wasn't allowing my distaste for the blink tag to affect my judgement.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?** and **is it unambiguous?**

It does describe the contents of the questions, in as much as there is something somewhere blinking in most of the questions. It is not unambiguous because it's not just about the `<blink>` element from HTML.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Sure, as long as the blinking is occurring somehow affectable programmatically.

**Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

Not really, as pretty much all of the questions have the word "blinking" in the title or body of the post, so it doesn't really help with searchability.

There are no followers of this tag.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Generally yes, although I've seen it used as meaning "shifting from one part of a view to another, rapidly" as opposed to switching visibility. That's likely a language barrier, or because there's no tag for "shifting from one part of a view to another, rapidly" :).

NB: The [blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blink) tag is on-topic, and is specifically about the browser engine powering Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: I really hope there isn't a `marquee` tag.

Comment: (from Wikipedia) Lou Montulli, often credited as the inventor of the blink element, has said that he considers "the blink tag to be the worst thing I've ever done for the Internet" - lol

Comment: I don't know about you, but I am an *expert* in blinking.

Comment: mulling over whether to follow the tag... :)

Comment: "Blinking - How Do I Know my Code is Still Running When my Eyes are Closed?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Progress

You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags and:

- flag or close questions that are duplicate/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion based;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value (re-tag), or;
- flag obsolete comments

Here are some easy links to get you started:

[blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blinking)

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bblinking%5D+closed%3Ano) 0
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bblinking%5D+closed%3Ayes) 0
- [No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bblinking%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0
- [No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bblinking%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) 0

[Review in the Close vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=blinking)

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority!

If you have specific questions feel free to drop in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room or leave a comment under this post.

Comment: Yep! I'm doing all the things I can for each post. I'll update this answer with that format.

Comment: [blinking] is burned! It will be automatically deleted by the system now. After a few days, if it doesn't appear, you can raise a custom-flag on this question so that it is marked [status-completed]. Thanks to all that contributed!

Answer (score 16):

Here are all the tags matching `*blink*`:

[blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blink)× 167

> an open source rendering engine forked from WebKit. It is included in Google Chrome 28+ and Opera 14+. Blink includes a different multiprocess architecture than WebKit2, and the V8…
>
> - 35 asked this year

[dblink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dblink)× 226

> An object or module that enables access to a remote database.
>
> - 5 asked this month, 56 this year

[blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blinking)× 140

> Alternate between being visible and invisible.
>
> - 23 asked this year

[opera-blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-blink)× 9

> Opera Blink refers to the Opera browser from (desktop) version 15 onwards, which uses the Blink rendering engine (a fork of WebKit).
>
> - 2 asked this year

[blinker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blinker)× 6

> Fast, simple object-to-object and broadcast signaling in python
>
> - 3 asked this year

I think that we should burn the blinking tag, and tidy the rest. There seems to be some abuse of the blink tag, in particular. I have already started cleaning some questions up.

---

From what little I gather, the [opera-blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-blink) tag is actually a subset of the [blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blink) tag. From a comparison of the two tags, it looks like adding a clarifying word to [blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blink) would prevent it from being abused.

As a side note, the [dblink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dblink) is an outlier here. It might be better to rename this one as well, to [db-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/db-link), so that it's a bit clearer. It's not immediately obvious that it means DataBase Link as it is now.

---

<sub>Lastly, if it is needed, a new tag can be created: [html-blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-blink) for all your burning questions about the `<blink>` [tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink). However, it's been deprecated in HTML5, and I don't see anything tagged with a blink that are about the tag, so my feeling is that **we don't need it**.</sub>

Comment: No, we don't need a new tag for the HTML element. Let it die in peace :).

Comment: And why should the tag be burnt? Any reasoning?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I can guarantee that there are several other tags out there that could be used instead. This one has lead to confusion and it is very vague.

Comment: What other tags could be used? (the `html-blink` suggestion looks reasonable by the way)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ While I'm not sure it is a better tag, [flicker] does exist.

Comment: One reason I could think is that almost all the questions have "blink" or "blinking" already in the question title.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Well, that was already mentioned in the question, so it's not like I disagree. :)

Comment: I remember a post made by animuson that he removed most (if not all) tags meant to be used about the html elements. He found that in most of cases they were used not because the question were about them, but just because their code included it somewhere.

Comment: @Braiam Nice to know. Yes, I see plenty of people that see that the code contains X and they suddenly must add tag X. It's probably not worth the hassle of maintaining...

Comment: @Laurel [flicker] is not the same as blinking. 'Flicker' refers to an _unintentional_ flashing of GUI elements due to the elements taking so long to draw that the screen blanking and redrawing the controls causes a visible (and annoying) flashing effect to the user. Preventing flicker is why a lot of GUI elements are double-buffered. The tag wiki for [tag:flicker] indicates that it's supposed to be used for that specific meaning, not just anything that's blinking.

Comment: @reirab Yes, I did read the wiki. I guess if you want to be technical, flickering is a specific type of blinking. Most of the time, neither tag is needed.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't think `<blink>` deserves a peaceful death. Burnination, dying in a [blinking](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/blinking) fire, is almost, but not quite, too good for it.

Comment: Blinking is achievable on a web page even in Chrome, but its a CSS or JavaScript technique, so an `html-blink` tag would be an inappropriate search for someone wishing to achieve it. Personal distaste for the practice should not be a factor.

Comment: @Alohci The entire point of proposing a "html-blink" tag was to ensure that it would be used for `<blink>`, nothing more.

Comment: @Laurel - Why would someone ask about the `<blink>`element if their goal was not to achieve some kind of blinking effect on a web page?

Comment: Well, a tag like `html-blink` or even `blink-effect` could probably be a better name. But I'm wondering how many questions could be created for such a tag. One could ask how to achieve such an effect using HTML/CSS, but that's the only use I see for a tag like that, no idea if that's enough to have its own tag, the amount of questions for such a tag would be very limited, and I guess nobody is a blinking-effect expert for all languages. Whether or not the HTML tag is deprecated doesn't really matter, I think. (People can still ask relevant things about deprecated stuff)

Comment: "dblink" is not about blinking (it's not "d-blink" but "db-link" where "db" is for "database"). I'm not saying it's a useful tag, but it does not belong into this list.

Comment: @g00glen00b But no browser supports blinking any more, neither with the `<blink>` element not with the `text-decoration` property. This is different from other deprecated features, which are still going strong (frameset, font, xmp etc) and which people can still ask about.

Comment: @MrLister you would be surprised by how many people are running an old browser or have to refactor old code. Besides that, you could always name the tag so that it's about the effect itself, which could be made using animations I guess?

Comment: @MrLister - text-decoration doesn't work, but css-animations do, and that opens a whole range of opportunities. Square wave, sine-wave, sawtooth and asymmetric transitions. Asynchronous blinking between elements. Blink sequences, like a lighthouse, come to mind. I'm not saying it's a rich vein, but there are definitely questions that can be reasonably asked on the theme.

Comment: I think the blink and bdlink tags should be renamed to make them clearer.

Comment: @Alohci That doesn't warrant a tag by itself. Not all css features need separate tags! I mean, what's next, a [repeating-linear-gradient](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/repeating-linear-gradient/info) tag? Oh wait.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Yes, I realized that once I started going through the tagged items. Oh mon-god-b, this isn't the first time my brain has done this `:)`

Answer (score -2):

One possible danger of removing [blinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blinking) is that users *might* start adding [blink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blink) to question about blinking stuff, without reading anything about what that tag is about. I don't think that this warrants keeping the tag, given the rather low number of questions tagged this way.

Comment: s/might/will.  We all know users to do not read tag descriptions.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/

Comment: @NathanOliver: The *might* was more tied in with the *start adding*. They might or might not decide to add a tag that's not exactly like the html tag name, but either way they will not read tag descriptions. But I think it's more likely that they will use the wrong tag than that they will not tag at all.

Comment: I think that problem can be fixed by simply renaming the blink tag, like Ian noted http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323641/if-youre-blinking-you-might-miss-it#comment347582_323643

Comment: @MvG The blink tag is already misused, which is why I suggested we clean up the whole set of tags. It's not a huge mess compared with other tags, fortunately. Renaming seems like a good option.

Comment: @MvG most people - especially new users - **never** read tag descriptions. Why give them another tag to abuse in some absurd way?